# How to add 2 on click functions in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the following code which copies values from one sheet to another when pressing B2. I have 20 different cells I want to be able to click which shall the display various texts from different tabs. I am struggeling to find a good solution to this problem. Any help would be appreaciated

```
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("B").Range("A:J").Copy Worksheets("A").Range("M:V")

    End If
End If
```

Comment: I _think_ you've got this in the `SelectionChange` event, but since your whole procedure isn't included, it's hard to tell. As it is, you're copying 10 whole columns from "B" to "A", so that's going to be more than 20 cells. Can you be more explicit about what you're attempting? Do you have 20 ranges of columns? Do you want 20 specific cells somewhere in those 10 columns?

Comment: Apologies new to this. I have 20 different cells i want to be able to click and to retrieve data from other sheets. B2,B3,B4... B20. When I click on B3 I want to copy columns A to J from sheet C to columns M to V in sheet A. When click on B4 I want to copy from Sheet D to Sheet a etc. I am at a pass on how to do this and any assistance would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Maybe anyone else who can advise?